# How to use command rm -r in mac terminal?

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

I'm just trying to delete a non empty folder (and sub contents) with the terminal on mac (folder is a non system folder, just a random testing folder placed on user desktop):

> rm -r foldername

It returns:

> rm: illegal option -- - usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
>
> unlink file

Does anyone know the right way to go about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> type -a rm

returns :

> rm is aliased to `rm --preserve-root'
>   rm is /bin/rm

**--preserve-root** is NOT supported on mac terminal.

Comment: `--preserve-root` is a GNU extension to the `rm` command, but macOS uses mostly BSD versions of command-line programs (including `rm`), so it doesn't support that. If you try to bring things directly over from linux to macOS, there are a lot of such differences you may run into. Also, don't consult the linux man pages when using macOS -- either use the `man` command directly, or use [an online copy of the macOS man pages](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html).